# Window onload event not triggered

Tags: javascript

I have a an object with an init function where I am initialising a select input field.

```
SelectBuilder.init();
```

The init method looks like this:

```
init: () => {
    const select = new MDCSelect(document.querySelector('.mdc-select'));
    select.listen('MDCSelect:change', async () => {
        if (select.value === state.data.selectedLocation) {
            return;
        }
        state.setState({ selectedLocation: select.value });
        let regions = geodata;
        let center = MAP_CENTER;
        let zoomLevel = window.screen.width < 600 ? 6 : 7;

        googleMap.panTo(center);
        map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
        drawRegions(googleMap, regions);
    });

    window.onload = async function () {
        console.log('loaded');
        const locations = await import('./assets/data/locations.json');
        const sortedLocations = locations.sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name));
        // init select items
        sortedLocations.forEach(location => {
            const list = document.querySelector('.mdc-list');
            const newListItem = document.createElement('li');
            newListItem.setAttribute('class', 'mdc-list-item');
            newListItem.setAttribute('data-value', location.ID);

            const listeItemIcon = document.createElement('i');
            listeItemIcon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-map-marker-alt');
            const listeItemText = document.createElement('span');
            listeItemText.setAttribute('class', 'mdc-list-item__text');

            listeItemText.appendChild(document.createTextNode(location.Name));
            newListItem.appendChild(listeItemIcon);
            newListItem.appendChild(listeItemText);
            list.appendChild(newListItem);
        });
    };
}
```

Since, I would like to postpone building of the select menu items until the page is fully loaded I have wrapped that in the window onload event. But, I can see with in the console that the event is never fired. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `window.onload` being overwritten anywhere else? You can use `window.addEventListener("load")` to avoid clashes.

Comment: Or maybe you invoke `init` method after window is loaded

Comment: @MarekSzkudelski that'd be my guess - you'd probably want to use something like `window.onload` to run your initial `JS` rather than what OP is doing.

Comment: that was it, I was overwriting onload method somewhere else